# How to insert data in two levels in firebase realtime database

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a firebase table called `users` in real-time database. The data structure of this table looks like

[image]

When I insert the user, it will insert the `name` and `email` of that user as a first level child and insert a token `token 1` inside a predefined `Tokens` node as a second level child. And I can then update the table by adding node in Tokens.

What I can do for a first level data insertion is

```
this.authService.db.database.ref(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable).push().set({
      UserName: this.NewDeployAdmin.name,
      UserEmail:this.NewDeployAdmin.email,
      Token: this.selectedDeploy.key,
      CreatedDate: this.formattedDateNow(),
      CreatedBy: this.authService.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
});
```

But I can not figure it out how can I achieve this type of insert and update operations?

Answer (score 1):

Do it like this:

```
this.authService.db.database.ref(FirebaseDb.firebasedeploymentAdminTable).push().set({
      UserName: this.NewDeployAdmin.name,
      UserEmail:this.NewDeployAdmin.email,
      Token: {
          token1: something,
          token2: something,
          token3: {
              deeperToken1: something,
              deeperToken2: something
          }
      },
      CreatedDate: this.formattedDateNow(),
      CreatedBy: this.authService.afAuth.auth.currentUser.uid
});
```